# Navigation Drawer button not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I added buttons in my navigation drawer. However, when i click the buttons. The application is forced to stop. There are no errors in the codes. Here is the Java file

```
package com.android.pet.view;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

public class Lesson111 extends Fragment {
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.onepointthree, null);

    /* Initialize Radio Group and attach click handler */
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

    /* Attach CheckedChangeListener to radio group */
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                if(null!=rb && checkedId > -1){
                    Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClear(View v) {
    /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also, here is the logcat.

```
03-27 07:36:12.185 24720-24720/com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer, PID: 24720
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClear(View) in the activity class com.android.pet.view.NavigationActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'clearBtn'
                                                                                       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3871)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4499)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18575)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClear [class android.view.View]
                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3864)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4499) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18575) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code for the XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What is ICT?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClear"
            android:text="Clear " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSubmit"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show the layout for the views that are you clicking.

Comment: The methods you set as `onClick` attributes in the layout XML must be members of the `Activity` class. They can't be in the `Fragment`. It would probably be preferable to set the `OnTouchListener`s dynamically, in this case. That is, use the `setOnClickListener()` method for your `Button`s in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, instead of setting the XML attribute.

Comment: @DougStevenson Im sorry, I didnt get your response. Are you saying that I need to show the xml file or a picture of the app?

Comment: @MikeM. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Dreamer Layout means XML.

Comment: @DougStevenson already updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button in your layout:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClear"
        android:text="Clear " />
```

It's saying that when it's clicked, to execute a method called onClear() in the activity that contains the view.

Your error message is saying that there is no relevant onClear() method in the activity.  You have an onClear in your fragment, but that's not an activity.  It only works with activities.

Instead of using android:onClick to specify the name of a method, it's almost always better to register an OnClickListener object in code.

Comment: How can I implement the onclicklistener in my code?

Comment: There's many great tutorials on that.  Search and give it a try, then if you have a specific problem, ask another question here.